# KSZ8895 Switch-Circuit Problem

Tags: network, network-interface

For an application I am trying to get a switch running using the KSZ8895 (standalone). For testing, at first, I connected it only to MagJacks.

[image: KSZ8895 Switch]

If I test the circuit and connect two PCs, this worked (tested with simple ping).

This works:

```
PC1 <-> Switch (KSZ8895) <-> PC2
```

But when I try to connect a PC over my switch to another switch, this fails.

This does not work:

```
PC1 <-> Switch (KSZ8895) <-> Another Switch <-> PCx
```

The two LEDS on my switch, which are connected to another switch are blinking synchronously at ~1 seconds intervals.

What's going wrong? Is there a fault in my circuit?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the datasheet for the strapping and configuration pin options.  I'm not sure whether they all float to a valid configuration (particularly SCONF0, SCONF1, PS0, PS1 and obviously MDIXDIS which is probalby the source of your trouble).

Also, try using a crossover cable to connect to the second switch, you might have auto-MDIX disabled with the default strapping options.

I also have a vague recollection that you have to supply reset logic, the internal reset is not reliable with all all power supply rail ramping possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I expected that the pins have there own internal pullups and pulldowns like in the datasheet described.

I added some external pull down resistors (1kohm) for SCONF0, SCONF1, LED5-1, PS1, PS0 and MDI-XDIS to GND. For the RESET i added a 1kohm pull up to 3,3volt. The trouble is the same as ask in my first post.

For my knowledge i think no more strap in options needed. But where is the problem still?

Comment: I can't offer any additional insight.  I use the KSZ8895 in an embedded application and auto-MDIX works just fine.  I am using SPI slave mode for configuration rather than the strapping options because I need programmable VLAN configuration, but there is a significant effort in implementing things that way.

Comment: Have you tried a crossover cable to verify that it is an auto-MDIX problem and not a negotiation problem?

Comment: Hello guys, sorry for the long delay. I got the KSZ8895 working. I made an pcb with all strap in options and it works well. I have only the point, that the 8895 get hot temperature..so you cant touch with your hands longer for some seconds. Is that normal?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have to remove the power supply delivery to the TCT, RTC pins. The KSZ8895 does not require it.